# Python popen - How do I search a file using file id in the network drive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen, network-drive

I have a python script which prints the file id from the file system. And it can search a file using its file id and prints the file full path. This works perfectly in the **local drive**. But I cannot search a file which is in the **network drive**.

```
def getFileId(filepath):
    print(popen('fsutil file queryFileId ' + filepath).read())


def getFilePath(fileid, directory):
    print(popen('fsutil file queryFileNameById ' + directory + " " + fileid).read())
```

'Z' is my **network drive**. When I call `getFileId(Z:\test.txt)`, it prints the file id correctly, for ex: 0x000123. But when I call `getFilePath(0x000123, Z:\\)` or `getFilePath(0x000123, Z:/)` or `getFilePath(0x000123, "Z:\")`, it throws an error "Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

So is it due to any limitation that the 'queryFileNameById' wont work within remote drives or am I passing the argument in wrong format?

Answer (score 0):

> am I passing the argument in wrong format?

This one.

First, the code you're showing does not work at all, `getFileId` does not *return* anything, it just prints stuff.

Second, the command you're using has a formatted output:

```
> fsutil file queryfileid foo.bar
File ID is 0x000000...0012345
```

but `queryfilenamebyid` only wants the actual id, so you need to extract that. Note that `queryfilenamebyid` has the exact same issue e.g.

```
> fsutil file queryfilenamebyid c:\ 0x12345
A random link name to this file is \\?\C:\Users\bob\foo.bar
```

Third, you should avoid `os.popen` as it's more difficult to control and compose commands, prefer `suprocess.run` to which you can pass a list of bits, this is a lot more reliable when dealing with strings which can contain strings, or "unsafe" input, and it has a lot more control knobs. Though the default is a touch worse as you need to ask it to `capture_output=True` or it just invokes the command and you get the status but not the stream outputs.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output()` :)

Comment: @Masklinn, actually I trimmed the "File ID is " from the output of queryfileid. And both  queryfileid and queryfilenamebyid works fine in local drive. My issue is with the queryfilenamebyid when trying to query a file within the network drive.

fsutil file queryfilenamebyid Z:\ 0x12345 --> Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @AKX is essentially deprecated.

Comment: @Masklinn As far as I understand there are no plans to deprecate it, and it's a very useful shorthand for doing exactly this.

Comment: @AKX it's documented in a section called "Older high-level API" just above "replacing older functions with the subprocess module" and which outright recommends using `subprocess.run` and mostly justifies its existence as "lots of existing code calls these functions". The doc of `run` also states it's the recommended approach.

Comment: Yes, I know - but not deprecated, no plans to deprecate. Sure, you can replace an invocation of `check_output(["foo", "bar"])` with `run(["foo", "bar"], stdout=PIPE, check=True).stdout` but you don't need to.

Comment: @AKX @ Masklinn I tried both:

subprocess.run(["fsutil file queryFileId ", filepath], capture_output=True).stdout
subprocess.check_output(['fsutil file queryFileId ', filepath])

But got this error for both:

File "...\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

And pls. note my problem is with queryfilenamebyid within a network drive (it works fine in local drives)

Comment: You should pass _either_ a string or a list of strings, not a list containing a single string with all the arguments mashed together.